# Plots not overlaying the y axis in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm doing this:

```
plt.xscale('log')
plt.plot(freq, magnitude, linestyle='--', marker='o', color='b', lw=2)
plt.plot(freq, magnitude_experimental, linestyle='--', marker='x', color='r', lw=2)
```

but the plots are not overlaying, just sharing the x axis (freq) and staying on top of one another. Both y axis have the same size. Isn't it suppose to overlay? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to be a bit more verbose - basically you need a reference to the axes you want to plot on:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(freq, magnitude, linestyle='--', marker='o', color='b', lw=2)
ax.plot(freq, magnitude_experimental, linestyle='--', marker='x', color='r', lw=2)
```